# Why the Html logs insertion insert space at the beginning of the first line?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

In an attempt to retrieve my web page's loggings, I opted to import the .log document into a separate page and proceeded to read it through the StreamReader. Despite utilizing the debbug tool, it was evident that the issue did not stem from my C# controller.

To conclude, this technique did not prove successful in identifying the underlying issue with my web page. However, it was a necessary step in the process of pinpointing the root cause.

Here is what i see in the webpage : [image: Using elmnt Inspector]

So as You can see, their is spaces inserted in the beginning, and two line are added also. whil using the debbug tool, only two line are imported so why is this happening ?

```html
<h2>Logs</h2>
<div class="logs-container">
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Rechercher..." />
    <pre id="logs-content">
        @Html.Raw(Model.TrimStart())
    </pre>
</div>
```

But in case, I give you the controller part

```
public IActionResult Logs()
      {
        // Remplacez "chemin_du_fichier" par le chemin d'accès réel de votre fichier de journalisation
        string logFilePath = "Logs\\FlexiArmLog-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
        string logContent;

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            logContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // Supprimez les espaces blancs du début de la première ligne des journaux
        logContent = logContent.TrimStart();

        return View("Logs", logContent);
    }
```

Comment: It's because there's whitespace inside the element's content ( new line and indentation) that gets reduced to a single space. Note the trailing space too. try it all on a single line without extra whitespace `<pre id="logs-content">@Html.Raw(Model)</pre>`

Comment: Yeah that was that! I really didn’t think of that at all, I knew in my debugging that its source was in HTML but I couldn’t tell why, experience difference I guess. Thanks Phuzi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like I had some issues with indentation in HTML. phuzy mentioned that I inserted an indentation thinking it would work, but it was considered and inserted in the view. One way to avoid this issue is to use the  tag in one line, which preserves both spaces and line breaks in preformatted text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).